# Retrieving Public Folders via Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365

I have an application that uses the Microsoft Graph API to read and write emails from a mailbox.

I'm making a request to URL

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/mailFolders/PublicFoldersRoot/childFolders`

This used to work, but since April 2021 it broke and now returns an error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorMailboxMoveInProgress",
        "message": "Mailbox move in progress. Try again later., Cross Server access is not allowed for mailbox UUID"
    }
}
```

No mailboxes have been initiated to move in my account.

I found the same thread on this issue, but there is no solution yet. [Mailbox move in progress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/403433/mailbox-move-in-progress-try-again-later-the-user.html).

I didn't find out any workaround. Please help if you know how to fix this.

Comment: I got the same error in the Export mail action in power automate when the same email is  capture in two flows

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the inconvenience caused to you.

Could you please check if there are any mailboxes being moved?
You can use Poweshell Cmdlet Get-MoveRequest to check if there are any active requests.

If there aren't any, this could be an intermittent issue and should resolve itself without your intervention
However, if this is critical and affecting your production workloads, please reach out to Support as it would be difficult to debug this remotely.

You can also check if there are any service issues affecting your subscription from the Service Health page

Hope this helps. Thanks!

Comment: There are no move requests in my account.

`PS C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7> Get-InstalledModule ExchangeOnlineManagement
PS C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7> $pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -AsPlainText -Force
PS C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7> $usr = "email"
PS C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7> $cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $usr, $pwd
PS C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7> Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $cred
PS C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7> Get-MoveRequest
PS C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7>`

Comment: This is an ongoing issue that I have been trying to resolve, I opened a support case with Microsoft 3 weeks ago and still no resolution.  This issue is happening to a quite a few people, there are other posts all with a very similar theme "this was working for years but now it is not", for me the error is now different, I also get "Cross Server access is not allowed for mailbox" but before it was "The user and the mailbox are in different Active Directory sites." so they are changing something on the backend, but zero response from Microsoft.

Comment: Check with your admin is there any activities planned to move the mailboxes or any org changes, due to that as well you may get such issues and check portal's service health page. Also just to isolate the issue, you may want to try using MFCMAPI utility or EWSEditor to see if you can access the public folders. These tools uses other non-Graph api, which can tell if you can able to connect with public folders of your org or not.

Comment: I am the Admin and no moves or org changes, have checked via powershell.  I don't see any issues in the portal service health, also this has been the error for 5+ months now so if it was a health issue I would assume it would have been fixed by now.  The movie function was working for almost 3 years, moved thousands of folders over that time and now error every time.  And again, I have been searching everywhere for an answer and have found multiple posts saying the exact same thing.  I bought a support contract from Microsoft to try solve this but no response so far.  thx